# Why req.session set in one route, not available in another route call?

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am using Express "express": "~4.13.1" and "express-session": "^1.11.3".
I have set my server like this :

app.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
app = express();

// view engine setup
var engines = require('consolidate');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', engines.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

 // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
 //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
 app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: false
 }));
 app.use(cookieParser());
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Using express-session in app with secret key
 app.use(session({
secret: 'mapdcs',
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true,    
cookie: {
    path: '/',
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false,
    maxAge: null
}
}));


app.use('/', routes);

app.use('/api/users', users);
```

index.js :

```
  // First call
  router.post('/adduser', function(req, res, next) {
    req.session.username = red.body.username;
    req.session.save();
    console.log('>>Session data From Add users');
    console.log(req.session); //I got the username session here
  }
  // Second call
  router.post('/check_auth', function(req, res, next) {
     console.log('>> Session data From check_auth');
     console.log(req.session); //Am not getting session here.
  }
```

Am trying to solve this issue since last two days. Can any one help in this please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have missing closing brackets ')' after the router calls, but I don't think that's the main issue. It has something to do with the request not sending a response / terminating correctly.

If you change the console.log(req.session)'s to something that sends a response e.g res.json(req.session), the second call works - see below for an example:

```
 router.post('/adduser', function(req, res, next) {
   req.session.username = red.body.username;
   req.session.save();
   console.log('>>Session data From Add users');
   // changed console.log to res.json 
   res.json(req.session)
 }); // Added the final closing bracket to router.post

// Second call
  router.post('/check_auth', function(req, res, next) {
     console.log('>> Session data From check_auth');
     // Changed the second console.log to res.json
     res.json(req.session);
  }) // Added another closing bracket
```

Hope this helps!

Edit: You could also just use res.end(), res.send() or res.render() - anything that generates a response - see the [Express response docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res).

Comment: @Ashiey B thanks for the reply. the missing brackets was by mistake here... not in my code in my system.  Well I tried your another option for the response but it's also not working in my case. Actually I think there is issue of package conflicting. Because I make another fresh setup of express app and session is working pretty fine in that setup. don't know what is wrong in this code.

Comment: Odd, sending a response (in  the '/adduser' call) fixed the code on my end. The only other thing I can think of is the ordering of packages, sometimes that can cause issues.

Check that the typo on this line doesn't exist in your code (red.body will be undefined):
req.session.username = red.body.username;

Comment: Yup  red.body.username is typo mistake here. in my code it's  perfect. and as i said am getting the session set variable in the same route as well, but don't know why it's got blank for another route. I think you are right , it will be issue of ordering of packages. let me try by changing it. Well thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the axios call and set `withCredential` to `true` to solve the problem.